# Randomizd String Searching

Tags: searching

I need to detect whether a binary pattern P of length m occurs in a binary text T of length n where m

I want to state an algorithm that runs in time O(n) where we assume that arithmetic operations on O(log2n) bit numbers can be executed in constant time. The algorithm should accept with probability 1 whenever P is a substring of T and reject with probability of at least 1−1n otherwise.

I think fingerprinting could help here. But I can't get it.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?  This is a nice exercise.  However, questions that just post your exercise and ask us to solve it for you are not appropriate for this site.  We expect you to make a serious effort on your own first, to tell us what you've tried, and where you got stuck.  If you have a specific, narrowly focused question about that, then it might be appropriate for this site.

Comment: If all you want is an algorithm with average time complexity in $\mathcal{O}(n)$, then naive search will do.

Comment: This was also posted on [CS Theory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19573/linear-search-in-array-algorithm-and-time-complexity-homework), and described there as homework.

Comment: Please do not replace your question by a reply or by another question. This is a [questions and answers site](http://cs.stackexchange.com/about), not a discussion forum. Each question has its own thread. To ask a new question, use the “Ask Question” button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average complexity of the search from the back to the front is equal to
$$
  \sum_{i=1}^n  \frac{2i}{n(n+1)}(n-i+1) = \frac{2}{n(n+1)}\sum_{i=1}^n i(n-i+1) = \frac{2}{n(n+1)} \frac{1}{6}n (n+1) (n+2) = \frac{1}{3}(n+2)
$$ 
which is indeed linear.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a common-sense heuristic would be to check the next most likely place first. This would suggest checking the array from the back to the front is optimal, since the target is more likely to be in higher positions.

The best and worst cases are the same as for vanilla linear search: in the best case, it's always the first element you check, and in the worst case it's always the last. The average case for linear search is also linear time, since you have to check roughly half of the elements (on average) to find the target. So the question we need to ask is the following: by checking the positions with highest probability, how many do we need to check to have at least a 50% chance of finding the target? It's a bit easier to answer this if we ask the question differently: how many positions can we check from the front, before we have a 50% chance of finding the target?